Calculate Components of square integrable functions w.r.t. some basis
Consider the space of square integrable functions on the non negative real numbers $L^2(\mathbb{R}_0^+)$. I found out, that the Laguerre functions modulo some normalization define an orthonormal basis for this space. The basis vectors I am considering are given by
\begin{align}
e_n=e^{-x/2}\frac{L_n(x)}{n!}
\end{align}
where $L_n(x)$ is the $n$-th Laguerre polynomial in x. The scalar product I am considering is
\begin{align}
\left<h(x),g(x)\right>=\int_0^\infty h(x)g(x)dx
\end{align}
as usual. What I now wanna do is to compute the components $\alpha_n$ of the square integrable function $f(x) = \sqrt{\beta}e^{-(\beta/2) x}$ in that basis, such that I can expand it as
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_n \alpha_n e_n
\end{align}
Note, that $||f(x)|| = 1$. To compute the coefficients $\alpha_n$ i have to evaluate the integrals
\begin{align}
\alpha_n = \left<f(x),e_n\right> = \frac{\sqrt{\beta}}{n!}\int_0^\infty dx e^{-(1/2)(\beta+1)x}L_n(x)
\end{align}
from which I find
\begin{align}
\alpha_n = \sum_{m=0}^n\frac{(-1)^m\sqrt{\beta}}{(m!)^2(n-m)!}\left(\frac{2}{\beta+1}\right)^{m+1}
\end{align}
My problem here is, that this does not make sense to me, since $f(x)$ should be normalized to one, therefore I should find $\sum_n\alpha_n^2=1$, which does not seem to be the case for any real $\beta$.
Do you guys see any conceptual mistake or did I just messed some calculation up? I am not really experienced in this kind of calculations.

In principle, I don't see any problem with your method, but I haven't checked the calculations myself. How did you calculate the coefficients?

I used the closed form of the Laguerre polynomials from the wikipedia article to evaluate the integral
